# Quadratic equation returns 0 in some cases

Tags: python, equation, quadratic

for example when i say x:9 p:3 q:2 it returns x1:(-0-0j) x2:-0-0j.
thanks for the help in advanced!

```
import math, cmath
from math import *
from cmath import *
x = input("input x value:")
pA = input("input p value:")
qA = input("input q value:")

p = int(pA)/int(x)
q = int(qA)/int(x)

solutionA = -(int(p)/2)
solutionB = cmath.sqrt(math.pow((int(p)/2),2)-int(q))
solution1 = solutionA-solutionB
solution2 = solutionA+solutionB

print("x1: {:g}".format(solution1))
print("x2: {:g}".format(solution2))
print ("x1:",solution1)
print ("x2:",solution2)
```

Comment: don't mind the double "print", i just wanted to try different methods

Comment: Have you considered using `numpy.roots()`?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?  Zero is, in fact, the result of your expression.  With your given inputs, both `p` and `q` are fractions less than 1, so `int(p)` and `int(q)` are both zero.  And 0**2-0 is still zero.

Comment: If you convert a float (e.g. 0.548) to an integer, python will round down. So if p = 3/9, you have the float 0.333, when you later call int(p), you change that into 0.

Comment: ok, thanks for the good answers

Comment: using float() instead of int() worked! thx